# Can't see the I've installed Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition Power Tools but can't see Checksum Unit Tests

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008

I've installed the **Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition Power Tools** but **can't see Unit Tests Conditions ChecksumCondition & ExpectedSchemaTestCondition**

I believe that it installed OK & I can see the new refactor commands so at least a part of it worked. Is there something I need to do to get the 2 new test conditions to display in the dropdown list of my tests?

FYI I"m looking for this feature.
*New Test Conditions for Database Unit Tests*

• **ChecksumCondition** – You can use this test condition to verify that the checksum of the data set returned by a database unit test matches the checksum of an expected data set.
• **ExpectedSchemaTestCondition** – You can use this test condition to verify that the column names and data types of the returned data set match expected values.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed "Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2"? If you have, then this is why you don't see the tests from the Power Tools. The Power Tools aren't compatible with GDR R2. The instructions for GDR R2 state that you are supposed to uninstall Power Tools before installing GDR R2. I ran into this same problem recently. Unfortunately installing GDR R2 means you no longer get those test from Power Tools. Because of this, I am actually writing my own Database Unit Test Conditions, one of which is similar to the ExpectedSchemaTestCondition from PowerTools.

Oh, I thought it might be useful as well if I pointed you in the right direction on how to create your own tests. This is the link that got me started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193287.aspx. If you need any guidance, let me know. I will probably be releasing the source to my custom tests, but I haven't completed it just yet.